# powershell md5 generator multiple lines

Tags: powershell, md5

how can i convert strings in a text file into md5. thanks!

For example:

```
1443476733
6336958878
3126096517
6987152905
4525279776
0575007755
3175657302
7247869712
0905161156
3419799574
```

Comment: take a look at ```Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5``` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is an MD5 hash of the whole file, just do

```
(Get-FileHash -Path 'X:\Somewhere\thefile.txt' -Algorithm MD5).Hash
```

If however you want to get an MD5 hash value for each line of text inside the file, more work is to be done, because Get-FileHash does not work on individual strings.
However, it DOES work with a Stream, so you can utilize that:

```
$stream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new()
$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($stream)
$result = Get-Content -Path 'X:\Somewhere\thefile.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $writer.Write($_)
    $writer.Flush()
    $stream.Position = 0
    # output an object containing the string itself and the calculated MD5
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        String = $_
        MD5    = (Get-FileHash -InputStream $stream -Algorithm MD5).Hash
    }

    $stream.SetLength(0)
}
$writer.Dispose()
$stream.Dispose()

# show on screen
$result

# or write to csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\StringsAndHashValues.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
String     MD5                             
------     ---                             
1443476733 427F17AB495EEE15AE7BBF9DC3A3BF03
6336958878 9E877ACC8E3BF71DEFE3A40F981614D6
3126096517 B675472559FC88340F806EA10CBD55A3
6987152905 D32EEA14F7F2DF72D3FFDA7862E13D82
4525279776 26FB60B461A9CA633EB5335525C6F659
0575007755 9A6D85E3D32E0DDC84BBDDBDC1728B62
3175657302 C4E8537F0C1C419739CB533DB73DDBB2
7247869712 053FFB162DA0C2034546CAE27122B95E
0905161156 0B42D95988BE1022409E318603D6C84D
3419799574 0FEBFC57A9DC73DD03C314A05A17F8C4
```

Comment: @rainbowpark Thanks for the nice feedback. Being new to the platform, may I point you to the [tour] where, amongst others  you can read how to mark your question 'done'.